# Filter multiple categories with a form

Tags: codeigniter, categories

I’m about to develop an events board in **Codeigniter**, where each event has multiple categories. I’ve figured that i should use a related table for events and categories, like described here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/152795/

The real deal is that I would like to have a categories filter, much like the one in [Authentic Jobs](http://www.authenticjobs.com/). Never mind the js goodness and animations, but I want to know the logic behind it.

1. The hardest thing for me is the
   multiple checkboxes that filter the
   query. How should I approach this?
2. Second, I guess the whole
   “preferences” are saved to a
   session, right? I wouldn’t use an
   URL for multiple categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that site is all ajax.

When a category is checked/unchecked a click event is triggered. An ajax call is made and the results are updated.

It's got nothing to do with Codeigniter per se.

```
Click category
Send ajax request with categories data
Query database using categories in a where clause
Update results
```